# How do I call a function with parameters?

Tags: swift

I am using xcode playgrounds toying around with some code and I get this error `Use of unresolved identifier 'colorArray'` when I try to call a function. How do I fix this I know it has to be simple.

```
import Foundation


class Solution{

var colorArray = ["Red","blue","green","black","red","blue","yellow","purple","Red","Red","Red","yellow","yellow","black","green","black","purple","black","yellow","purple","purple","blue","yellow","blue","green","green","yellow","pink"]

func getMostCommonColor(array: [String]) -> [String] {
    var topColors: [String] = []
    var colorDictionary: [String: Int] = [:]

    for color in array {
        if let count = colorDictionary[color] {
            colorDictionary[color] = count + 1

        }else{
            colorDictionary[color] = 1
        }
    }
    let highestValue = colorDictionary.values.max()

    for (color,count) in colorDictionary {
        if colorDictionary[color] == highestValue {
            topColors.append(color)
        }
    }

    return topColors
}
}
let solution = Solution()
solution.getMostCommonColor(array: colorArray) //This is where I get the error
```

Comment: I think your calling it outside of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've defined it, `colorArray` is an instance property of `Solution`, meaning you need to access it through some instance of the `Solution` class.

You've already created an instance down below, so you *could* do this:

```
let solution = Solution()
solution.getMostCommonColor(array: solution.colorArray)
```

However, I suspect you meant for `colorArray` to be a global variable of sorts (since this is just a playground, after all), so another option is to move `colorArray` *out* of the `Solution` class:

```
var colorArray = ["Red","blue","green","black","red","blue","yellow","purple","Red","Red","Red","yellow","yellow","black","green","black","purple","black","yellow","purple","purple","blue","yellow","blue","green","green","yellow","pink"]

class Solution {

    func getMostCommonColor(array: [String]) -> [String] {
        var topColors: [String] = []
        var colorDictionary: [String: Int] = [:]

        for color in array {
            if let count = colorDictionary[color] {
                colorDictionary[color] = count + 1

            }else{
                colorDictionary[color] = 1
            }
        }
        let highestValue = colorDictionary.values.max()

        for (color,count) in colorDictionary {
            if colorDictionary[color] == highestValue {
                topColors.append(color)
            }
        }

        return topColors
    }
}

let solution = Solution()
solution.getMostCommonColor(array: colorArray)
```